Gravity Output given error if field is empty
I am using Gravity to collect a form and using PHP to echo it. It is't showing error if a field is empty instead of leaving it blank, can anyone please help?
Here is the error:

Warning: Undefined variable $value in /home/......functions.php on
line 169

My code is
//get gravity forms fields by form field id
function get_gf_form_fields_value_by_id($entry_id,$field_id){ 
    global $wpdb;
     $results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT meta_value FROM {$wpdb->prefix}gf_entry_meta WHERE  meta_key = $field_id AND entry_id = $entry_id LIMIT 1 ", OBJECT );
    foreach($results as $result){
        $value = $result->meta_value;
    }
    return $value;
}


It sounds like your query returns no results, executes foreach loop zero times, then tries to return non-existent variable $value. What if you declare $value outside the loop?

Gravity Forms has a function called rgar which can retrieve the value from an entry object, without writing any SQL. (GF used to be called Rocket Genius, in case you were wondering about the function name.) If you don't have an entry object, you can retrieve it with GFAPI::get_entry($entry_id). I would encourage you to use the official functions unless there's a specific reason you cannot.
